# Linux Apache2 Ubuntu12.04

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток, господа и товарищи =)

Помогите с настройкой Virtualhosts в Apache2 на базе Ubuntu 12.04

У меня вопросик назрел, весьма актуальный (для меня весьма сильно)

*Суть вопроса:*

**Задача:**

- *Развертываем* на рабочей машине на
     базе Ubuntu 12.04 сборку Lamp
     (Apache2 + Php + MySQL)
- *Настраиваем* 5 виртуальных хостов
     (example1x.comp, example2x.comp,
     example3x.comp, example4x.comp,
     example5x.comp) причем таким образом
     что где .comp -это имя машины в
     локальной сети.
- *Настраиваем* необходимые моды и
     конфиги для видимости в рабочей
     сети...

---

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2 php php_mysgl mysgl

Answer (score 1):

Так в чем сложность то?

1. Cтавим `LAMP - sudo apt-get install lamp-server`
2. Pаходим в `/etc/apache2/sites-available`
3. `cp default example1x.comp` (поправьте этот файл чтоб параметры сайта указывали на нужный вам имя сервера, каталог, лог-файл)
4. Перезапустить апач (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`)
5. Набрать в строке браузера `www.example1x.comp` и проверить правильность загрузки страницы (на всякий случай в файле `/etc/hosts` прописать 127.0.0.1 `www.example1x.comp`)